# Range query in prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator, promql

I have a metric (pkts_sent) and it has a couple of parameters (switchname and port). I need to fire an alert based on the condition that if number of pkts_sent is below 1000 but it could be fired only for ports 1 to 10. I am not sure how i could create a range of the ports in the query.

pkts_sent {portid=~[1-10]} < 1000 does not work as all the ports between 1 to 10 is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a valid PromQL query (there are no quotes around the expected value of `portid`) and `[1-10]` is not a valid regular expression (which is what `=~` expects).

Try this instead:

```
  pkts_sent{portid=~"[1-9]|10"} < 1000
```